# Clearing a file after reading with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there any built in way to read a file with SSIS and after reading it clearing the file of all content?

Answer (score 2):

Use a File System Task in the Control Flow to either delete or move the file.  If you want an empty file, then you can recreate the file with another File System Task after you have deleted it.

My team generally relies on moving files to archive folders after we process a file.  The archive folder is compressed whereas the working folder is uncompressed.  We setup a process with our Data Center IT to archive the files in the folders to tape on a regular schedule.  This gives us full freedom to retrieve any raw files we have processed while getting them off the SAN without requiring department resources.

Answer (score 1):

What we do is create a template file (that just has headers) and then copy it to a file of the name we want to use for processing.